# Equivalence between submodular function definitions.

Tags: measure-theory, definition

I am trying to show that the definitions, given by wikipedia, of a submodular set function are equivalent. See section definition of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function. Mainly I want to show that 2 if and only if 3. I succeeded with 3 implies 2. Can anybody help with 2 implies 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See slide 30 onwards of these lectures by Jeff Bilmes: http://melodi.ee.washington.edu/~bilmes/ee595a_spring_2011/lecture2.pdf

Comment: [These notes on submodular optimization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.6453v2.pdf) contain similar proofs that are easier to read, in my opinion. You can find the proofs on page 10.